# How to find random element matching to condition in a table?

Tags: java, loops, conditional-statements

I've made a table with geometrical figures and a for loop for printing out the name of figures that have right angle, but I would like to print out one random name for this figure that matches the condition and if it's possible create another table that contains only figures that match the condition. I was trying to use some method from `java.util.Random` but I couldn't find out how. I'll be thankful for Your help:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class rectangularFigures {
    private String name;
    private boolean rightAngle;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public rectangularFigures(String name, boolean rightAngle) {
        this.name = name;
        this.rightAngle = rightAngle;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        rectangularFigures[] lOFigures = new rectangularFigures[4];

        lOFigures[0] = new rectangularFigures("whell", false);
        lOFigures[1] = new rectangularFigures("square", true);
        lOFigures[2] = new rectangularFigures("rhombus", false);
        lOFigures[3] = new rectangularFigures("rectangle", true);

        for (int i = 0; i < lOFigures.length; i++) {
            {
                if (lOFigures[i].rightAngle) {
                    System.out.println(lOFigures[i].name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See this https://www.oreilly.com/learning/generating-a-random-number-in-java

Comment: if you want something as random as possible the best choice I know of in java would be to use SecureRandom, it is a random number generator suitable for cryptographic applications, for an example look at Example 4 from https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/java.security.SecureRandom

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use java streams:

```
rectangularFigures[] onlyRightAngles = Arrays.stream(lOFigures).filter(x -> x.rightAngle).toArray(rectangularFigures[]::new);
    rectangularFigures randomElement = onlyRightAngles[new Random().nextInt(onlyRightAngles.length)];
    System.out.println(randomElement.name);
```

But if for some reasons you can't use streams, i suggest to use ArrayList and traditional foreach loop:

```
List<rectangularFigures> onlyRightAngles = new ArrayList<>();
    for (rectangularFigures figure : lOFigures) {
        if (figure.rightAngle) onlyRightAngles.add(figure);
    }
    rectangularFigures randomElement = onlyRightAngles.get(new Random().nextInt(onlyRightAngles.size()));
    System.out.println(randomElement.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a small example but it can be improved:

```
    Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < lOFigures.length; i++) {
        {
            int f = r.nextInt(4);
            if (lOFigures[f].rightAngle) {
                System.out.println(lOFigures[f].name);
            }
        }
    }
```